# Puppeteer - Retrieving links from divs with specific class names

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

There are divs with class="xj7"
Below that , there is an a=href link.

How can i access the value of the a link? What makes it even trickier is that there are many elements with the same classname - so ideally i want to loop through them.

Another hindrance is that the link is in relative form. That means it doesn't specify the domain name. It is like this:

```
<div class="xj7">
    <a href="/tst/gfhe7sje">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works.

```
async function run(){
    await page.goto('<url_here>');
    let div_selector= "div.xj7.Kwh5n"; 

    let list_length    = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
            let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
            return elements.length;
    }, div_selector);

    for(let i=0; i< list_length; i++){
        var href = await page.evaluate((l, sel) => {
                    let elements= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
                    let anchor  = elements[l].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
                    if(anchor){
                        return anchor.href;
                    }else{
                        return '';
                    }
                }, i, div_selector);
        console.log('--------> ', href)
    }
    await browser.close();
}
run();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. But document.querySelector(sel), there is no variable sel to pass as argument. Also, i just noticed my class name is "xj7 Kwh5n", so how would that change the div_selector variable?

Comment: No, if you look at the `page.evaluate` function, at the end of the function we have passed variable `div_selector` which is catched/received in variable `sel`. Basically this is how we pass variable into page.evaluate.
Also, the new selector will become "div.xj7.Kwh5n"

Comment: I got this error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: @user1584421 I have updated my answer. Sorry for taking the liberty of posting answer without testin :) The problem in earlier code was we were returning DOM content from page.evaluate(), which is not possible. But we CAN return the value, thus now we are first returning the length, then performing the extraction of `href` in page.evaluate itself and returning the link. I have tested this code this should be running

Comment: My friend, the code worked flawlessly... I cannot describe enough how thankful and indebted i am to you. Thank you for taking the time to write code to help me. Your manners were impecable as well. I really hope i would be able to hear more from you in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
const crawl = async (url) => {
  try {
    console.log(`Crawling ${url}`)
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)

    const selector = '.xj7 > a'
    await page.waitForSelector(selector)
    const links = await page.$$eval(selector, am => am.filter(e => e.href).map(e => e.href))

    console.log(links)

    await browser.close()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

crawl('https://example.com')
```