# Puppeteer: select by class, but only first element

Tags: node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

There are several div classes "jadejhlu" containing a a=href link. How can I select only the first div class to get only one link? I tried

```
const selector = 'div.jadejhlu > a'
const links = await page.$$eval(selector, am => am.filter(e => e.href).map(e => e.href))
console.log(links)
```

like it is explained here: [Puppeteer - Retrieving links from divs with specific class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788997/puppeteer-retrieving-links-from-divs-with-specific-class-names)

I get a list of links. I could also try to extract the first link of this list. Or I could try to insert a [0] to select only the first div.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [$eval](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) instead:

```
const selector = 'div.jadejhlu > a'
const links = await page.$eval(selector, (el) => el.href);
console.log(links)
```

Comment: Sometimes it works well, sometimes I get "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child` method to select the first element only.
Something like this:

```js
const selector = 'div.jadejhlu > a:nth-child(1)'
```

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work here.

Comment: Well, we need more details to understand why this do not work here

Comment: it doesn't change the result. I still get a list of more than 20 links.

Comment: Again, we need more details to get better answer. can you share a link to that page?

Comment: A facebook album like https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1072904782727149&type=3